# Named-entity recognition with trained data

Tags: r, nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

My text file t1.txt contained this

```
<START:name> Ashish Sanadhya <END> , 61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .
Mr . <START:name> mayank sharma <END> is chairman of Elsevier N.V. , the Dutch publishing group .
```

and t2.txt contained

```
person mayank sharma
persons ashish sanadhya
organizations linkedin
```

I have  trained the data as the image shows[image]
but when tried to get back for the desired result as in

```
>s <- paste(c("I am ashish ."))
> a2 <- annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
> entity_annotator <-  Maxent_Entity_Annotator(language = "en", kind = c("person"), probs = FALSE,model ="C:\\apache-opennlp-1.5.3\\en-ner-person.bin")
>  entity_annotator(s, a2)
  [1] id    type  start end  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

and i was expecting the result after trained the person entity

```
 entity_annotator(s, a2)
 id type   start end features   
 1  entity 6    11  kind=person
 s[entity_annotator(s, a2)]
 ashish
```

any help ,why am I not getting expected result.thanks ,any help in this direction

**EDITED**

i have downloaded file **en-ner-person.bin** from [here](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) and **cutoff** parameter work for me,i used this command

```
c:\apache-opennlp-1.5.3>bin\opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer -cutoff 1 -lang en -encoding UTF-8 -data "c:\t7.txt" -model en-ner-person.bin
```

hope it help and special thanks to Daniel Naber.

Comment: What  happens if you try the sentence "I am Ashish."? Note the capital letter.

Comment: I don't know about the namefinder, but other OpenNLP tools have a default cutoff, so you need a certain amount of training data to get useful results.

Comment: @mbatchkarov not working, getting the same result.

Comment: @DanielNaber i have posted my trained text file ,would u like to have look on it.

Comment: @Aashu So what happens if you specify ```-cutoff 0``` or ```-cutoff 1```?

Comment: @DanielNaber "c:\apache-opennlp-1.5.3>bin\opennlp TokenNameFinderEvaluator -encoding UTF-8 -cutoff 0 -model en-ner-person.bin -data "c:\t4.txt"
Unrecognized parameters encountered: [-cutoff, 0]"

Comment: @Aashu That parameter is needed at training time, not when using the evaluator.

Comment: can someone answer this question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383509/number-of-parameters-must-be-always-be-even-opennlp