# Number of parameters must be always be even : opennlp

Tags: java, command-line-interface, opennlp, training-data

I've been trying to use the command Line interface to train my model like this:

```
opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer -model en-ner-pincode.bin -iterations 500 \ -lang en -data en-ner-pincode.train -encoding UTF-8
```

the console output is:

```
Number of parameters must be always be even
Usage: opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer[.evalita|.ad|.conll03|.bionlp2004|.conll02|.muc6|.ontonotes|.brat] [-factory factoryName] [-resources resourcesDir] [-type modelType] [-featuregen featuregenFile] [-nameTypes types] [-sequenceCodec codec] [-params paramsFile] -lang language -model modelFile -data sampleData [-encoding charsetName]
```

It works fine if I don't include the number of Iterations.
Does anybody know the reason behind this?

thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you keep `-iterations` but remove another options, say `-lang`?

Comment: no,same error even if i remove -lang! :/

Comment: What's that hanging \ in the middle ? Is it a newline or was it actually part of the command ?

Comment: /its a part of the command as given in the docu

Answer (score 1):

Actually the issue is

```
    -params paramsFile
            training parameters file.
    -iterations num
            number of training iterations, ignored if -params is used.
    -cutoff num
            minimal number of times a feature must be seen, ignored if -params is used.
```

If anyone use `params` then `iterations` and `cutoff` are ignored. So for your case this info message is shown.

### Resource Link:

1. [Tokenizer Training : Training Tool](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.tokenizer.training.tool)

### UPDATE:

So, Please use `ChunkerTrainerME` instead of `TokenNameFinderTrainer`

Your command should look like below

```
opennlp ChunkerTrainerME -model en-ner-pincode.bin -iterations 500 \ -lang en -data en-ner-pincode.train -encoding UTF-8
```

---

### UPDATE2: Converting the data

I will use Spanish data as reference, but it would be the same operations to Dutch. You just must remember change “-lang es” to “-lang nl” and use the correct training files. So to convert the information to the OpenNLP format:

```
$ opennlp TokenNameFinderConverter conll02 -data esp.train -lang es -types per > es_corpus_train_persons.txt
```

Optionally, you can convert the training test samples as well.

```
$ opennlp TokenNameFinderConverter conll02 -data esp.testa -lang es -types per > corpus_testa.txt
$ opennlp TokenNameFinderConverter conll02 -data esp.testb -lang es -types per > corpus_testb.txt
```

Training with Spanish data

To train the model for the name finder:

```
\bin\opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer -lang es -encoding u
tf8 -iterations 500 -data es_corpus_train_persons.txt -model es_ner_person.bin
```

### UPDATE3: Converting the data (optional)

To convert the information to the OpenNLP format:

```
$ opennlp TokenNameFinderConverter conll03 -lang en -types per -data eng.train > corpus_train.txt
```

Optionally, you can convert the training test samples as well.

```
$ opennlp TokenNameFinderConverter conll03 -lang en -types per -data eng.testa > corpus_testa.txt
$ opennlp TokenNameFinderConverter conll03 -lang en -types per -data eng.testb > corpus_testb.txt
```

Training with English data

You can train the model for the name finder this way:

```
$ opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer.conll03 -model en_ner_person.bin -iterations 500 \
                                 -lang en -types per -data eng.train -encoding utf8
```

If you have converted the data, then you can train the model for the name finder this way:

```
$ opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer -model en_ner_person.bin -iterations 500 \
                                 -lang en -data corpus_train.txt -encoding utf8
```

Comment: so, what to do if i want to increase the number of iterations?

Comment: He's not using `-params` in his original call though, so I don't see how that's related

Comment: It gives the same error, but why ChunkerTrainerME? I don't understand

Comment: @Nuwanda On that case, you can convert your data type and then check with `TokenNameFinderTrainer`

Comment: convert datatype to what?

Comment: @SkyWalker even that didn't help! getting the same error!

Comment: Sorry for that. Then it is my last try. Please check the update 3 portion.

Comment: @SkyWalker what is that file eng.train? the one i have in .train format right?

Answer (score 0):

From "https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html#intro.cli"

> ```
> Usage: opennlp TokenizerTrainer[.namefinder|.conllx|.pos] [-abbDict
> path] ...  -model modelFile ...
> ```
>
> The general structure of this tool command line includes the obligatory tool name (TokenizerTrainer), the optional format
>   parameters ([.namefinder|.conllx|.pos]), the optional parameters
>   ([-abbDict path] ...), and the obligatory parameters (-model modelFile
>   ...).

So the parameters are either things starting with "." or with "-", and there needs to be an even number of them. There are examples in the documentation that seems to agree with this.

Comment: i've tried it removing -lang, now it has 4 params but shows the same error :/

Comment: Ah, thought I had something... Side question, do you use the `\\` in your command line? Could that be the source of your error? I doubt it, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: no,i tried without / and it won't recognize -iterations then!

Comment: @Nuwanda oh that's it then, definitely

Comment: The backslash in the documentation is there to mark newlines. Don't put it in your command!

Comment: What do you mean it didn't workout ? Is is the same error ?

Comment: not the same, it says Unrecognized parameters encountered: [-iterations, 500]

Answer (score 0):

A short answer, `iterations` is not a parameter for TokenNameFinderTrainer.  You can see that from the question where the recognized parameters are listed in the console output.